# get_posts not return all post, with multiple custom post type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Thank you for read

i have passes $args variable it contain following args.
this args variable pass in get_posts method.
it will give only quiz_4,quiz_0 posts. where i am doing mistake

```
Array
(
    [posts_per_page] => 20
    [paged] => 1
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => quiz_4
            [1] => quiz_0
            [2] => quiz_5
            [3] => quiz_3
            [4] => quiz_2
            [5] => quiz_1
            [6] => password
        )
    [orderby] => menu_order title
    [order] => ASC
    [post_status] => any
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `numberposts => 20` instead of `posts_per_page`.

**$args**

(array) (Optional) Arguments to retrieve posts. See [WP_Query::parse_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) for all available arguments.

`'numberposts'`
(int) Total number of posts to retrieve. Is an alias of $posts_per_page in WP_Query. Accepts -1 for all. Default 5.

**Reference:**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/